# Can you reset progress in a Blood Bowl 2 Competition?

Tags: blood-bowl-2

Because Blood Bowl 2's ranking system seems to but a ridiculous amount of weight into losses if you lose one match due to bad dice you are basically screwed.

So is there any way to reset your involvement in a competition back to 0-0-0 when this happens?

For example I'm in the veteran ladder and won 7 games, now I've lost 2 so basically it's pointless playing any more.

I tried leaving the competition then rejoining but it still says my record is 7--0-2.

Is there any way to wipe the results clean and start again without having to train up a whole new team and possibly have the same thing happen?